# jQuery + CSS - where 4th div is coming under 3rd div, wrap 3 div in one line, and 4th - on next line

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an ASP.Net-MVC view, which adds `div` dynamically, if data is available for that section. The requirement is such that 3 `div`s should be accommodated in single line.

Have a look at this **http://jsfiddle.net/tKKDY/4/**

I have this CSS

```
.section {
    border: 1px solid Red;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
}
```

And html like this

```
<div class='section'>hello</div>
<div class='section'>
  hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
</div>
<div class='section'>hello</div>
<div class='section'>fourth hello</div>
<div class='section'>hello</div>
```

The problem is, the text content is not fixed length. Due to that, the fourth `div` takes its place under the third `div`. To fix this, I can have a `CSS` class like this.

```
.row {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

Using this, I have to make the content of `parentDiv1` as `parentDiv2` as explained in jsfiddle. How can i achieve this using `jQuery`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, use `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left` on your sections, and you won't need `.row`:

```
.section {
    border: 1px solid Red;
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tKKDY/5/

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery does it...

```
$('#parentDiv1').filter(':visible').find(':lt(3)').wrapAll('<div class="row">');
```

Get's first 3 `div`s and wraps it with new `div`, so.....

**http://jsfiddle.net/tKKDY/7/**

Answer (score -1):

Here you go :)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tKKDY/6/)

change row to

```
.row {
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anobik. I think we are miscommunicating. I just used `row` class so that the 4th `div` - having `section` class - takes its place in the next line.

Comment: where exactly the 4th div needs to be placed ?

Comment: As already showed in my jsfiddle - below the comment in the result <--This is how it should look--> in the next line